# Spring Kafka commit reset offset not work when application goes down

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

As described in the documentation, an offset should only be committed when I actually commit (When AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE or AckMode.MANUAL) or at the end of the listener execution when AckMode.RECORD, however, in the middle of processing the method annotated with @KafkaListener the application goes down, the message is not re-delivered, the application starts reading from the next valid message and this current message is lost (message that was being processed when the application was restarted), how do I achieve the goal of the application reprocessing an uncommitted message when the application is restarted in the middle of processing? I have also tried configuring AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG as earliest, latest and none without success in the 3 models. For testing purposes, I created a topic with just one partition, I forced the listener to use the container factory that I define manually.
The springboot-version 2.2.6

```
    @Configuration
    class KafkaTestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        fun producerFactory(): ProducerFactory<String, String> {
            return DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(producerConfigs())
        }

        @Bean
        fun consumerFactory(): ConsumerFactory<Any, Any> {
            return DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(consumerConfigs())
        }

        @Bean
        fun producerConfigs(): Map<String, Any> {
            val props: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
            props[ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "localhost:9094"
            props[ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringSerializer::class.java
            props[ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringSerializer::class.java
            return props
        }

        @Bean
        fun consumerConfigs(): Map<String, Any> {
            val props: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
            props[ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "localhost:9094"
            props[ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java
            props[ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = StringDeserializer::class.java
            props[ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG] = 20000
            props[ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG] = "kafka-retry"
            props[ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG] = "earliest"
            props[ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG] = "false"
            return props
        }

        @Bean
        fun kafkaTemplate(): KafkaTemplate<String, String> {
            return KafkaTemplate(producerFactory())
        }

  @Bean
    fun kafkaListenerContainerFactory(): ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Any, Any> {
        val factory: ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Any, Any> = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory()
        factory.consumerFactory = consumerFactory()
        factory.consumerFactory.createConsumer()
        val containerProperties = factory.containerProperties
        containerProperties.isAckOnError = false
        containerProperties.ackMode = AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE
        containerProperties.commitLogLevel = LogIfLevelEnabled.Level.INFO
        containerProperties.isLogContainerConfig = true
        return factory
    }

    @Component
    class KafkaListenerAck {
        @KafkaListener(id = "listMsgAckConsumer", topics = ["kafkaListenerTest1"],
                groupId = "kafka-retry",
                concurrency = "1",
                containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory"
        )
        fun onMessage(data: ConsumerRecord<String, String>, acknowledgment: Acknowledgment?) {
            println("listMsgAckConsumer1 - topic ${data.topic()} offset ${data.offset()} partition ${data.partition()} message ${data.value()}")
            println("If stop container here, the next pool will not deliver the current unconfirmed message")
            acknowledgment?.acknowledge()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offset will not be committed until the `acknowledgment.acknowledge()` is called. Set the `commitLogLevel` container property to `DEBUG` to see commit activity.

`auto.offset.reset` only applies if the consumer has never committed an offset (new consumer groups only).

If you can't figure it out from the log; edit the question with the log snippet.

Comment: Hello Gary Russel, Many thanks, work as well, The container finish the method and commit offset, only if I force to kill the process (kill -9) the commit does not occur and the message is re-delivery